# Two Custom Post Types with Identical Articles Competing for the same Slug

Tags: posts, slug, customization

I have created two custom post types, each with it's own slug.  Each custom post type contains some articles with the same title.

So ideally I would have . .

customposttype1/mainarticle/

customposttype2/mainarticle/

Instead I get . . .

customposttype1/mainarticle/

customposttype2/mainarticle2/  <-- with the extra 2 on the end

The permalinks are set to "postname".

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is normal WordPress behaviour. Any time it detects that a slug is a duplicate - regardless of post-type or parents or categories - it will append a number to differentiate the newer version. As far as I know, there is no way to override this.